# select table1 and count of table2

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like this

table1

```
orig1 orig2 orig3 xref1 xref2 xref3
1      1     1     2     2     2
1      1     1     3     3     3
23    23    23     12   12    12
```

table2

```
orig1 orig2 orig3 xref1 xref2 xref3  version
1      1     1     1     1      1       0


expected output:-

orig1,orig2,orig3,count_table2
1,1,1,1
```

I am trying to select the first 3 columns in table1 and count(*) from table2. I tried like this

SELECT 
    orig1,orig2,orig3 from table1,
    COUNT(table2.*) as t2,
FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN tabel2 ON table1.orig1 = table2.orig1

Its printing NUll only. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should normilize the tables to somethings like  `origin` columns `id. origin_number` and `value` then it's much eaizer to use COUNT query on the tables.

Comment: @RaymondNijland any example

Comment: No even close to valid sql,Never mind producing null.

Comment: @P.Salmon yeah I know. I am not that good in sql.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's not clear what your expected output is - you could clarify by adding expected output to the question.

Comment: @P.Salmon i have posted expected output

Comment: try this out: select count(*), table1.orig1,table1.orig2,table1.orig3 from table1 right join table2 on table1.orig1 = table2.orig1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say your expected output makes sense to me but you can get your desired result like this

```
drop table if exists table1, table2;
create table table1(orig1 int,orig2 int,orig3  int,xref1 int,xref2 int,xref3 int);
insert into table1 values
(1   ,   1  ,   1   ,  2  ,   2  ,   2),
(1   ,   1  ,   1   ,  3  ,   3  ,   3),
(23  ,  23  ,  23   ,  12 ,  12  ,  12);

create table table2(orig1 int, orig2 int, orig3 int,xref1 int,xref2 int,xref3 int, version int);
insert into table2 values
(1 ,     1  ,   1  ,   1   ,  1  ,    1  ,     0);

select distinct t1.orig1,t1.orig2,t1.orig3,obs
from table1 t1
join
(select t2.orig1,count(*)  obs
from table2 t2
group by t2.orig1) t2
on t2.orig1 = t1.orig1;

+-------+-------+-------+-----+
| orig1 | orig2 | orig3 | obs |
+-------+-------+-------+-----+
|     1 |     1 |     1 |   1 |
+-------+-------+-------+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I think effort could be more sensibly invested in revising the schema